# Triangle bisector area problem

Tags: geometry

If X is any point on the internal bisector of angle A , Prove that $Area(BAX)/Area(CAX)=BA/AC$

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Answer (score 1):

Note,

$$\frac{Area(BAX)}{Area(CAX)} = \frac{\frac12 BA\cdot AX\sin \frac A2}{\frac12 AC\cdot AX\sin \frac A2} = \frac{BA}{AC}$$